# issue while using jupytab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tableau-api

I am trying to connect the jupyter notebook to the tableau desktop for which I am using jupytab library.

can you please help me in running below mentioned command

jupytab --config=config.ini

Comment: Welcome to SO community! Please be more specific with what you've got, and which errors you have if any so someone could help you.

Comment: please refer to the link  https://libraries.io/pypi/jupytab-server.     and i want to know how to run the the abpve mentioned command in jupytab server

Comment: refer to the documentation: https://github.com/CFMTech/Jupytab#installation